# How can I successfully escape apostrophe using php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, apostrophe

I know this has been asked many times before but I'm still stumped.
I'm obviously missing something but I have been unable to figure out how to successfully escape the apostrophe when sending a mysql query from php. Why does this not work when everything I have read says it should.

```
<?php
$title = "havin' fun";
$con=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title); 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,artist,title FROM songs WHERE title     = '$title'");
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];   
    $artist = $row['artist'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo $id.' - '.$artist.' - '.$title.'<br>';
    }
}else echo 'No Results';
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements you shouldn't escaped.

Comment: are you saying nothing you read uses the function properly?

Comment: Note, your escaping isn't working because you don't have the connection in the function. `$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title);`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php From the manual...`mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title);// add another parameter for connection
```

For example:

```
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title)
```